# What is the difference between $request->merge() and $request->mergeIfMissing()

Tags: http, merge, request, laravel-8

Basically, I'm creating a middleware to check user permission related to their subscription.
I need to add permission data to user's request before it came to Controllers.
I found $request->merge() can do that.

Laravel Doc says:

> Sometimes you may need to manually merge additional input into the request's existing input data. To accomplish this, you may use the merge method:

```
$request->merge(['votes' => 0]);
```

> The mergeIfMissing method may be used to merge input into the request if the corresponding keys do not already exist within the request's input data:

```
$request->mergeIfMissing(['votes' => 0]);
```

So I create a test route, a middleware, and registered in Kernel:

```
// web.php
Route::get('test', [PortalController::class, 'showHomePage'])->middleware('check.user.permission')->name('test');

// Kernel.php
'check.user.permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserPermission::class,

// CheckUserPermission.php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->merge(['permission' => 'free']);
    dd($request->permission);
    return $next($request);
}
```

If I do merge() or mergeIfMissing() I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not merging any key which already exist in the initial request.
merge(): the new data will overwrite the old value.
mergeIfMissing(): will keep it.

##### Merge()

Merge() method combines the elements of one array or collection with another array or collection. If there are duplicate keys, the values from the second array or collection will overwrite the values from the first one.

```
$collection1 = collect(['permission' => 'not free']);
$collection2 = collect(['permission' => 'free']);

$result = $collection1->merge($collection2);

// Output: ['permission' => 'free']
```

The value of key 'permission' in $collection2 overwrites the value from $collection1.

##### MergeIfMissing()

MergeIfMissing() method merges the elements only if the keys from the second collection are not already present in the first one.

```
$collection1 = collect(['permission' => 'not free']);
$collection2 = collect(['permission' => 'free']);

$result = $collection1->mergeIfMissing($collection2);

// Output: ['permission' => 'not free']
```

Since the key 'permission' already exists in $collection1, it is not overwritten with the value from $collection2.